# How to avoid blocking function g_application_run

Tags: gtk

I have an application with the following pattern (it's an embedded application) that I don't want to change:

```
void
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  some_init_functions();
  while(1) {
    some_functions();
  }
}
```

I'd like to simulate the application on Windows so I'd like to use Gtk+3 to show a window that simulate the display used in the original application.

The problem is the function g_application_run() that is blocking.

Is it possible to manually call a Gtk+/GLib function to process pending events only and returns immediately? I would call this function in the while(1) loop.

I read about gtk_main_iteration_do(), but I didn't understand how to use it without calling g_application_run().

Answer (score 1):

It's your job to integrate your application in the GUI, not the other way around. What you should do is call `g_application_run`, and add an event source with `g_timeout_add` or `g_idle_add` that will call your callback. In that callback, just call `some_functions()` once. The GTK main loop will take care of calling it again and again.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get out of the `g_application_run` loop. Events can be handled by [`g_main_context_iteration(GMainContext *context, gboolean may_block)`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-iteration). With `may_block = TRUE`, it will only return to the main loop after an event has been handled. With `may_block = FALSE`, only the highest priority events will be handled after which control returns to the loop.

The code below is based upon the `example-0.c` code from the [GTK Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5), yet making the process flow from `g_application_run` explicit. Note that command line arguments are not processed, and several checks are omitted.

A timeout event is added such that, in combination with `may_block = TRUE`,  the main loop advances at least once per second. Also, a callback is added on the `destroy` event, such that, in combination with a global variable, the main loop can stop if the window is closed.

As a direct answer to the question asked: you would need to make sure correct set-up and break-down is performed, and add `g_main_context_iteration (context, may_block);` to your `while (1)` loop.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static bool application_running;  // As use_count is private

// Add close_window event watcher to tell our application loop we should stop
static void
close_window (void)
{
  printf("Window is closed\n");
  application_running = FALSE;
}

// Add timeout to make sure the application loop is unblocked once per second
static gboolean
timeout (gpointer data)
{
  printf("timeout\n");
  return true;
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);

  // Add destroy call-back so we know when window is closed.
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (close_window), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);

  g_timeout_add_seconds (1, timeout, NULL);

  // **** begin g_application_run alternative ****
  // Setup
  GMainContext *context;
  gboolean acquired_context;

  context = g_main_context_default ();
  acquired_context = g_main_context_acquire (context);
  g_return_val_if_fail (acquired_context, 0);

  GError *error = NULL;
  if (!g_application_register (G_APPLICATION (app), NULL, &error))
    {
      g_printerr ("Failed to register: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);
      return 1;
    }

  g_application_activate (G_APPLICATION (app));

  // Main event loop
  application_running = true;
  int loop = 0;
  while (application_running) {
      bool may_block = TRUE;
      // may_block = TRUE: g_main_context_iteration blocks execution if no events are coming
      // may_block = FALSE: g_main_context_iterations processes pending events and continues
      g_main_context_iteration (context, may_block);
      printf("Loop %i\n", loop++);
    }

  // Release
  g_settings_sync ();
  while (g_main_context_iteration (context, FALSE)) 
    ;
  g_main_context_release (context);
  // **** end g_application_run alternative ****

  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```